# css doesn't load in this project. but css working smoothly in other projects

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot

Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String indexmethod(){
        return "index";
    }
```

css file location : \src\main\resources\static\index.css

jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>cascascascascas</h2>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Found the Solution. A specific @requestmapping(value="...") option in
  Controller class block the static file.. I just delete that specific
  @reqestmapping and after that i get access to static folder. I am
  keeping this question. So that, it can help other to solve same
  problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```